# Line break in select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, html-select

Hi I am using select2 dropdwon

Code is similar to bellow

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single id='select2'>
<option value="10">this is a option x <br>value is 10</option>
<option value="20">this is option y<br> value is 20</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
<script>
```

This way line break doesn't work, how do I make it work or what else I can use to break line?

Comment: Why do you want `<br>` in an option text ? It could be done via other nicer ways instead of this. Please add more info on how and why you want the line break ?

Comment: Option texts are a bit long. So I want break line in a specific place not randomly break by whitespace. Like break only in dot(.) or wherever I put a tag to break it

Comment: Apply some css to control the width of your `select2`  Add this CSS in your style sheet `select2-container {max-width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a recognizable placeholder in the text of your options, you can search for it and put a line break in the select2 plugin. For this you can simply use the [template functions](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) of select2.

But you must not forget that for example screen readers or the google search engine will only see your placeholders and not necessarily the replaced text. So choose your placeholder carefully.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function templateResult(item, container) {
    // replace the placeholder with the break-tag and put it into an jquery object
    return $('<span>' + item.text.replace('[br]', '<br/>') + '</span>');
  }

  function templateSelection(item, container) {
    // replace your placeholder with nothing, so your select shows the whole option text
    return item.text.replace('[br]', '');
  }

  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    templateResult: templateResult,
    templateSelection: templateSelection
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="select2">
  <option value="10">this is a option x [br]value is 10</option>
  <option value="20">this is option y[br] value is 20</option>
</select>
```